# Vuetify themes with custom css

Tags: vuetify.js

Let's assume I have something like the following:

```
<v-app>
  <div :class="getCustomCss">Blah</div>
<v-app>

getCustomCss() {
  return $this.vuetify.theme.dark ? 'whenThemeIsDark' : 'whenThemeIsLight';
}

<style>
  .whenThemeIsDark {
    border:1px solid white;
  }
  .whenThemeIsLight {
    border:1px solid black;
  }
</style>
```

What would be the best way to change the color of the divs border when toggling between light/dark themes?

Do I sit and watch the $this.vuetify.theme.dark property and manually change the border from the myDarkClass to myWhiteClass similar to what's shown above?  Or do I somehow use the customProperties feature in the theme/options to do this (and how?).  Or is there a better way of doing this I'm unaware of?

This is a simple example which only requests the css to change in one spot, but a real application may have tons of custom css on different pages that would keep needing checks like this. I could easily see that getting messy if there are watchers/checks everywhere.

I have read the https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme page and I have a feeling the Custom Properties section may be the key, but I'm not quite getting how to translate my example to their example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A css class of `theme--light` or `theme--dark` is applied to the v-app `v-application` which will identify which theme is active for you without additional watchers.

Using your simplified example:

```
<style>
  .v-application.theme--light {
    border:1px solid white;
  }

  .v-application.theme--dark{
    border:1px solid black;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks that's great to know. It seems like that is a master css at the top level though. How do we do it for individual items?  Like if I have 10 different tables, each with their own class? Should I do .v-application.theme--light someClass {  ?

Comment: Yes that should work.
Using nested CSS with preprocessors such as SCSS or LESS would make this a little cleaner and easier to maintain. Vuetify 2 is now using SCSS

Answer (score 0):

The `.v-theme--dark` class just worked for me in a Vue 3 code base.

Why does this work? In brief, the current Vuetify version introduced a `v-` prefix to many of their older classes.

```
th {
  background-color: white;
}

.v-theme--dark {
  th {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps someone.